# Marker on google map using Mysql,Php,Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I have San Andreas map http://prntscr.com/drd9pz i add some markers using fallow code:

```
var burgInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: '<h3>Burg</h3><p>Ovo je mesto gde se igraci cesto okupljaju i zajedno jedu burgere.</p>'
});
var burgMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(1195.3125,-925.78125),
    map: map,
    icon: 'https://wiki.sa-mp.com/wroot/images2/0/0e/Icon_10.gif'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(burgMarker, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(burgMarker.position);
    burgInfoWindow.open(map,burgMarker);
});
    //Uncomment to show an alert with the position when you click on the map
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        var pos = SanMap.getPosFromLatLng(event.latLng);
        alert(pos.x + "," + pos.y);
    });
```

Now i want to add markers with location from MySQL base like markers for house,so i take X,Y location of that house from my DB http://prntscr.com/drdaf8 and load X,Y and try to create markers but not work,this is code for that:

```
<?php
    $kuca=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM kuce WHERE `kId` > 0");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($kuca))
    {
        $x = $row['kUlazX'];
        $y = $row['kUlazY'];
        echo        
        "<script>
        var houseInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<h3>Kuca</h3><p>Ovo je mesto gde igraci zive.</p>'
        });

        var houseMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: SanMap.getLatLngFromPos($x,$y),
        map: map,
        icon: 'https://wiki.sa-mp.com/wroot/images2/b/b6/Icon_31.gif'});

        google.maps.event.addListener(houseMarker, 'click', function() {
        map.setCenter(houseMarker.position);
        houseInfoWindow.open(map,houseMarker); </script>";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: This is most likely a timing-issue. What is the error you get?

Comment: http://5.230.28.164/map/ here is my map on VPS and work great but not load this..And i think it dont have any errors.

Comment: The JS console shows you any error?

Comment: `(index):191 Uncaught ReferenceError: addMarker is not defined(…)` shows up a couple of times in the console. That's part of the problem.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` (the event listener function isn't closed).  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/k0ea426p/)

Comment: But how add example marker for the Burg and normall work?

Comment: It doesn't have that syntax error (see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/k0ea426p/), which has the error fixed).  If you had created a [mcve] you would have seen the issue.

Comment: Yes i can add marker like you do,but me need to add marker with x,y from MySQL DB

Answer (score 0):

How your logic works? I don't know. But you have missed **})** this.

Please change

```
houseInfoWindow.open(map,houseMarker); </script>";
```

Into

```
houseInfoWindow.open(map,houseMarker);}) </script>";
```

Comment: But all(http://prntscr.com/drdhr6) this is javascript because google map me need only x,y for location which will be create houses,if i add there </script> what will happen with the rest?